# How do I find the total of a particular model attribute in a collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

How do i find the total of a particular attribute in the models of a collection?

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ });

var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model :  myModel,
});
```

Whenever there is a value change in the models, I have to show the total of all the values.

For example, I have 10 models in the collection and there is a property in the models called `amount`. I should show the total of `amount` whenever the property gets a new value.

The code I used :

```
debitAmountTotal: function(){
    return this.reduce(function(memo, value) {
        return memo + value.get("amountTcy");
    }, 0);
}
```

but this concatenates the values : if the first value is 8 and the second value is 8 then the result is 88 instead of 16

Comment: `+` concatenating indicates that your `amountTcy` values are actually strings, you should convert them to numbers before they get into the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. assign default value of 0 to amount in each model.
2. Bind a `changed` event to models of the collection, and add/remove to the collection.
3. For the `changed` event, use [reduce](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) method of underscore.js to iterate over the collection and find the sum of amounts.

Comment: The collection's `"add"` and `"remove"` might also be of interest.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks , it would be helpful if you could provide some code snippet

Comment: @DhruvPathak Thanks , it would be helpful if you could provide some code snippet

Comment: or `all` if you are planning to subscribe to all 3

Answer (score 0):

```
debitAmountTotal: function(){
    return this.reduce(function(memo, value) {
        return memo + Number(value.get("amountTcy"));
    }, 0);
}
```